# Is there a limit on how many emails I can add in PHPMailer's method: addAddress()?

Tags: php, email

I'm using PHPMailer and I have to send mail to +50 different recipients, but for some reason, the mail isn't being delivered to everyone. Is there a limit while using this function?

PS: I'm storing the +50 users in an array, and I use a foreach() to iterate over each of them and use the addAddress() on each one.

Comment: I don't believe there's a limit in the PHPMailer library itself, but it's probable that your mail host has a limit. You could batch it into smaller groups, but generally, you'll want to send 50 emails to 1 recipient instead of 1 email to 50 recipients.

Comment: @AlexHowansky is correct. This is often not a limitation of PHPMailer, but rather your mailserver, or SMTP service that you're using. For instance, [AWS SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/quotas.html#quotas-sender-recipient) has a 50 recipient quota for messages that are sent out.

Comment: To go even further, unless you are using it in SMTP (or maybe including, too, I don’t know much about that mode), if a single message gets through, the problem isn’t with PHPMailer because it has relayed to an MTA.

Comment: Thank you guys, could it be, possibly, that there's an IT policy blocking inbound mail inside the company? Because the email is being delivered to approximately 30/50 people that need to receive it.

Comment: It's possible your mail server is just taking the first 30 recipients and ignoring the rest.

Comment: Email deliverability depends on the reputation of the IP that is sending the mail. Using PHPMailer usually results in low inboxing rates due to the fact that recipient mail servers likely have never seen email come from your server before. If you are sending bulk mail, you should look into services that build reputation on their sending IPs like AWS SES or SendGrid.